# Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable error when using multiple outputs from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dask

This code:

```
@dask.delayed
def sum_nr(a,b):
    return a+b, a, b

for i in range(10):
    sum_ab, a, b = sum_nr(i, i+1)
```

produces

```
TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable
```

What is a different way of outputting multiple items from a function, in dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `compute` call as specified in the documentation.

```
for i in range(10):
    sum_ab, a, b = sum_nr(i, i+1).compute()
```

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that calling `.compute()` on `delayed` output immediately generally makes sense. `delayed` must be just avoided in those cases.

For those who are facing that issue in situations where a use of `delayed` is reasonable, there are other options.

## Option 1: `nout` argument

```py
@dask.delayed(nout=3)
def sum_nr(a,b):
    return a+b, a, b

for i in range(10):
    sum_ab, a, b = sum_nr(i, i+1)

# You need to call .compute() on necessary outputs at the end
```

## Option 2: Explicit indexing

```py
@dask.delayed
def sum_nr(a,b):
    return a+b, a, b

for i in range(10):
    res = sum_nr(i, i+1)
    sum_ab, a, b = res[0], res[1], res[2]

# You need to call .compute() on necessary outputs at the end
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.